# How to prove that $f(x)=e^{x}$ is not a polynomial.

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

It is obvious that if we differentiate $f(x) = e^{x}$ with respect to x we will get again and again $e^{x}$. Can we conclude anything by considering the behavior at $\pm\alpha$

Comment: A degree $n$ polynomial will be the zero function if one derives it more than $n$ times.

Comment: Show that $f(x)\ne0$ for any $x$ is one manner of proof.

Comment: From @ThomasRot: $\frac d{dx}[e^x] = e^x$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, for this, one would have to specify that $x$ should be allowed to be complex.

Comment: the only polynomial that goes to $0$ as $x\to -\infty$ is constant.

Comment: Find all polynomials such that $f(x)\,f(-x)=1\,$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\pm \alpha$?

Comment: Two distinct polynomials differ at a point. A polynomial and its derivative are distinct polynomials (unless it's zero).

Answer (score 7):

If $f(x)$ is a polynomial then

$$f(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_0$$

and $f^{(n+1)}(x)=0$, which is a contradiction because

$$f^{(k)}(x)=e^x>0$$

for all $k$

Answer (score 6):

Without using differentiation, but with using limits:

---

Suppose $f(x)$ is a polynomial such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=e^x$.

Let the degree of $f$ be $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let the cofficient of $x^n$ be $a$. Since this is the leading coefficient, it must be nonzero.

Since $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n$ must be even or odd.

- If $n$ is odd and $a$ is positive, then $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}  f(x) = \infty$$
- If $n$ is odd and $a$ is negative, then $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}  f(x) = -\infty$$
- If $n$ is even and $a$ is positive, then $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}  f(x) = \infty$$
- If $n$ is even and $a$ is negative, then $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}  f(x) = \infty$$

We know that

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} e^x = 0$$

This forces us to conclude that $a$ is neither positive nor negative, which means $a$ must be zero. That's a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

One can use the fact that $x^{n} /e^{x} \to 0$ as $x\to\infty$ for any $n$. If $p(x) $ is polynomial of degree $m$ choose $n=m+1$ and then $x^{n} /p(x) \to \pm\infty$ and hence $p(x) \neq e^{x} $. The same limit property of $e^{x} $ can be used to prove that $e^{x} $ is not an algebraic function. See [this answer to a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1820789/72031).