# Logarithm as quotient of polynomials

Tags: calculus, polynomials, logarithms

Show that the function $\log x$ cannot be expressed in the form $f(x)/g(x)$, where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials with real coefficients.

Comment: Don't tell people what to do. Also, at least pretend you're interested in doing at least some of your own work.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Presumably you mean $\log |x|$ yes?

Comment: What tool can I use?

Comment: Try to give some insight about your thoughts or approach to the question...

Comment: More generally one can show that $\log x$ is not an algebraic function. See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1820789/72031

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\log(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ for polynomials $f, g$.

Because $\log(x)$ isn't bounded for $x\to \infty$, we must have $\deg(f)>\deg(g)$.

But we have
$$\log'(x)=\frac{1}{x}=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-g'(x)f(x)}{g(x)^2}$$
and so

$$g(x)^2=xf'(x)g(x)-xg'(x)f(x)$$

and we get the $2\deg(g)=\deg(xf'(x)g(x)-xg'(x)f(x))$.

But $\deg(xf'(x)g(x)-xg'(x)f(x))\leq \deg(g)+\deg(f)$ and so to get no contradiction with $\deg(f)>\deg(g)$, the leading coefficient of $f'g$ and $g'f$ must be the same. But the leading coefficients are the leading coefficients of $fg$ multiplied with $\deg(f)$ in the first case and $\deg(g)$ in the second. And so we also get a contradiction namely $\deg(f)=\deg(g)$.