# Show that not exists any polynomial function such that $f(x) = \log (1+x)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

Does anyone have any idea on that problem?

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial function. Show that not exists any $f$ such that $f(x) = \log (1+x)$.

It's easy to show that $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 1$. But after i don't have any idea. Any point? Thanks!

Comment: Take the limit to infinity of f(x)/x.

Comment: Or a limit to $x \to -1^{+}$

Comment: This is a bit of a dumb answer, but polynomials exist and are continuous $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, whereas $\log(1+x)$ is not.

Comment: More generally [logarithm is not an algebraic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1820789/72031). The current question is very easily handled by noting that derivative of a polynomial is also a polynomial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe there are many ways to show this; but what I have in mind is this:
If $f$ is a polynomial of degree $k$, then its $(k+1)$-th derivative is zero. 
But this is not the case for $\log(1+x)$; the $(k+1)$-th derivative of $\log(1+x)$ does not vanish.

Answer (score 1):

If there was, then it would not be constant and we would have$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(x+1)}{f(x)}=1.$$But, for every non-constant polynomial function, we have$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(x+1)}{f(x)}=0.$$

Answer (score -1):

If $\log(1+x)$ is polynomial, $f$ is a transcendental polynom function which doesn't exist.